# What is the dihedral angle formed by the faces of a tetrahedron

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, 3d

**Background**

Dihedral angles are angles that are formed by two intersecting planes

and no this is not a duplicate i check everyone possible duplicate because there is a slight variation that changes the problem in each

**question**

A regular tetrahedron is a triangular pyramid in which all four faces are equilateral triangle. find the acute dihedral angle between two faces of regular tetrahedron to the nearest tenth of a degree

Comment: Did you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49330/the-dihedral-angles-of-a-tetrahedron-in-terms-of-its-edge-lengths/1493653#1493653) asks for the dihedral angle of a general tetrahedron in terms of its edge lengths. [I chose to answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49340/409) by giving a formulas in terms of face areas (because those relations deserve to be better-known). Most-relevant here is this version, for a tetrahedron $OABC$, ...
$$W^2=X^2+Y^2+Z^2-2YZ\cos\angle OA - 2ZX\cos\angle OB-2XY\cos\angle OC \tag{$\star$}$$
where $W := |\triangle ABC|$, $X := |\triangle OBC|$, $Y := |\triangle AOC|$, $Z := |\triangle ABO|$ are face areas, and $\angle OA$, $\angle OB$, $\angle OC$ are dihedral angles along respective edges $\overline{OA}$, $\overline{OB}$, $\overline{OC}$.

In a *regular* tetrahedron, all face areas are equal ($W=X=Y=Z$), as are all dihedral angle measures ($\angle OA = \angle OB = \angle OC$), so $$W^2 = 3 W^2 - 6W^2\cos\angle OA \qquad\to\qquad \cos\angle OA = \frac{1}{3} \tag{$\star\star$}$$

I'll leave calculating the angle measure itself to the reader. $\square$

---

**FYI ...** The $0$-dimensional *point*, $1$-dimensional *segment*, $2$-dimensional *triangle* and $3$-dimensional *tetrahedron* have higher-dimensional counterparts, each known simply by the umbrella term ["$n$-dimensional simplex"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) (or "$n$-simplex"). The bounding elements (counterparts of "vertices", "edges", and "faces") are called "facets", and we can write, for $n\geq 2$ ...

> **Fun Fact.** The angle between two neighboring facets of a *regular* $n$-simplex is $\operatorname{arccos}\frac{1}{n}$ .

So, always remember and never forget: $\cos 60^\circ$ isn't merely "half of one"; it's *the reciprocal of the equilateral triangle's dimension!*