# amino acid dihedral angles from distances between 4 points (atoms)

Tags: geometry, 3d

I wish to compute the angles between 4 atoms from the distances between them.  I can use the law of cosines to work out the two simple triangles, but I am struggling to find a (hopefully elegant) solution for the dihedral.

The ASCII art below describes my preferred system: triangle ABC is on the XZ plane (Y=0), with B on the origin and C on the +Z axis.  Triangle BCD rotates D around the Z axis, so x and y coordinates for D are the unknown values (but my current goal is the dihedral angle, not the coordinates):

```
        |
        |  D
   \    | /
    \   |/
     \  C
      \ I
       \I
--------B---------- x
       /|\
      / | \
     A  |  \
        |   \
        z    y
```

My goal now is to get the dihedral angle rotation for ABCD from the distances AB, BC, CD, AC, BD and AD.

I expect there will be a chirality issue (2 points on the circle traced by D about the Z axis with the same AD distance), but I believe I can solve this with other constraints.

Helpful direction, advice or implementation detail you may have will be very much appreciated.

Edit: I have implemented the algorithm referenced in the comments in [Biopython version 1.80/1.81](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/NEWS.rst), specifically the [distance_to_internal_coordinates()](https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.PDB.internal_coords.html#Bio.PDB.internal_coords.IC_Chain.distance_to_internal_coordinates) routine.  I was unable to resolve the chirality issue and require this data as an input.

Comment: dihedral angle are angle between two planes. Are you asking for the angle between the planes holding $ABC$ and $BCD$?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["The Dihedral Angles of a Tetrahedron in terms of its edge lengths"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/49330/409). See, in particular, [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49340/409).

Comment: @achillehui - yes, the angle between the planes holding ABC and BCD along the edge BC

Comment: @Blue YES!  I am pleased to report that your solution works for me (with the +/- chirality issue expected). Thank You So Much!  I'm also pleased to note that I would not have come up with anything lke that solution, nor recognised the relationship to the earlier question had I not asked.